# Garrus is taking forever to fix the AA gun

Tags: mass-effect-3

Garrus seems to be stuck during the mission *Arrae: Ex-Cerberus Scientists*. What can I do to help him? Cerberus attacked and I killed them all. Now dramatic music is playing but nothing is happening. What can I do?

Comment: You can start by giving more details, e.g. which mission you're talking about. Or you could try reloading an autosave.

Comment: He's just doing some calibrations...

Comment: not sure what i should answer this with.

Comment: I *think* the OP is talking about the mission *Arrae: Ex-Cerberus Scientists*. Pretty sure it's the only one with Cerberus and fixing AA guns.

Comment: I have the same issue. I reloaded a save twice, but still can't get past this point. There's a cerberus shuttle that looks like it's just stuck in midair, though no one is in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Missions will "stall" like this if there is an enemy hiding somewhere, as the game is actually waiting for combat to end, not a timer.

You can usually flush out remaining enemies by running out from cover, or failing that, meticulously checking every nearby nook and cranny for hiding enemies.

Comment: I had an invisible phantom hiding on the lower level. Took forever to find her, but eventually I did.

Answer (score 2):

Try reloading an old save point...might just be a bug

Answer (score 1):

I reloaded last save game after the above bug and choose my other ally to activate the AA gun and i didnt mount the gun this time and it worked for me, maybe try this if you have this issue

Answer (score 1):

The AI for the invisible phantom is a little buggy, so expect this to get stuck somewhere and be stupid hard to find. There is a quick save right before the second switch so just load the last save and when the phantom drops nuke the ever loving crap out of it before it disappears.